# adjust angular 5 code to display on cell phones

Tags: angular

I am new to angular...
I have an angular app that also need to work on cell phones .
I am using primeNG grid to divide the screen to columns (class="ui-g") so each row has 12 columns

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/grid

but in the cellular display from what I understand there are less columns ? 
in this way when I change the px of the screen (using F12 and changing the size of the screen ) I  see there are less columns
what is the right way to develop an angular app that will also support all size of screen ?
I mean that it will shrink the screen proportionally 
and not change the number of columns

**UPDATE**
here is the code i am using ( i move the logic - only the html ) but when trying to view it on a cellphones the cells are not next to each other )

```
<div class="ui-g ui-sm ui-md">
  <div class="ui-g-12  ui-sm-12  ui-md-12">
    <div class="ui-g-7 ui-sm-7 ui-md-7">


      <div class="ui-g  ui-sm ui-md">
        <div class="ui-g-12  ui-sm-12 ui-md-12">
          <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <div class="ui-g-12  ui-sm-12 ui-md-12 ui-md-12">
              Please provide us with feedback with your experience ,your rate and/or leave comments
              <br> this is to help us provide you with a better service
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-2 ui-md-2">First name *</div>
            <div class="ui-g-1 ui-sm-1 ui-md-1"></div>
            <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-2 ui-md-2">Last name *</div>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <input class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-2 ui-md-2" type="text" pInputText name="firstName" maxlength="20" />
            <div class="ui-g-1 ui-sm-1 ui-md-1"></div>
            <input class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-2 ui-md-2" type="text" pInputText name="lastName" maxlength="20" />
          </div>
          <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-2 ui-md-2">Middle name</div>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <input class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-2 ui-md-2" type="text" pInputText name="middleName" maxlength="20" />
          </div>
          <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-2 ui-md-2">UMN *</div>
            <div class="ui-g-1 ui-sm-1 ui-md-1"></div>
            <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-2 ui-md-2">Phone number *</div>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <input class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-2 ui-md-2" type="text" pInputText name="umn" maxlength="15" />
            <div class="ui-g-1 ui-sm-1 ui-md-1"></div>
            <input class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-2 ui-md-2" type="text" pInputText name="phoneNumber" maxlength="10" />
          </div>
          <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <br> Service experience *
          </div>
          <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <div class="ui-g-12  ui-sm-12  ui-md-12">
              <p-radioButton name="quickFeedBackGrade" value="1" label="Very poor"></p-radioButton>
              <p-radioButton name="quickFeedBackGrade" value="2" label="Poor"></p-radioButton>
              <p-radioButton name="quickFeedBackGrade" value="3" label="Good"></p-radioButton>
              <p-radioButton name="quickFeedBackGrade" value="4" label="Very good"></p-radioButton>
              <p-radioButton name="quickFeedBackGrade" value="5" label="Excellent"></p-radioButton>

            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-3 ui-sm-3 ui-md-3">
              Comments
              <textarea rows="5" cols="60" pInputTextarea autoResize="autoResize" name="comments"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is how it should be [image: desktop]

this is cellphone display [image: cell display]

Comment: The amount of columns won't change, that's why it's up to you to specify columns for lg, md, sm, and utilize the media queries built in that will trigger them and is how your design is responsive. You might look more into `ui-lg-*`, `ui-md-*`, `ui-sm-*` and how they work. Cheers

Comment: And cell phones also have 12 colums? So what you are saying is that every time i have ui-lg-* i need to add ui-sm-*?

Comment: Yes, as example. `<div class="row"><div class="ui-md-6 ui-sm-12"></div><div class="ui-md-6 ui-sm-12"></div></div>` would make two columns on same row for medium and large screens, and then stack the two cells on top of each other full width for small (mobile) screens. The grid doesn't change it's structure, but you have to provide ability for its content to.

Comment: Sorry,but I still dont understand...when you write md-6 isn't that means that from medium device the number of cells will be 6? Why do you say 2 columns for medium and large when you wrote md-6 and sm-12? Sorry ,can you please explain some more, and thank you very very much

Comment: You always have 12 columns available, if you give 6 to one cell, and 6 to another, that makes up a row of 12. So both cells will have 6 columns of width within the width provided for a row. If you specify 12 on each, then each cell will span the full 12 columns available. I'd suggest consulting [the documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/grid) for better explanation, most of the grid systems of all UI frameworks (like bootstrap, foundation, etc) all work this same way. :)

Comment: Ahhh of course...i understand now

Comment: Ahh of course i undestand now,thank you very much !!will try tomorrow

Comment: No worries, come on back if you run into issues, cheers!

Comment: Criss , i still can't make it ... i update the Q with the code - can you lease see what i am doing wrong ? 
Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you're not following the documentation? If you peek at the snippet it's more in line with what you're after but I would strongly suggest learning the basics of how it works if you're going to use it often or you'll only frustrate yourself. For example, `ui-grid-row` is invalid and doesn't exist. Also the parent that begins the grid needs to be `ui-g` to declare it as a grid, and declarations like `ui-g-3 ui-sm-3 ui-md-3` are redundant, all that would be required in that scenario is `ui-g-3` once.

Anyhow, take a peek at the changes below. The Radio Buttons aren't going to display because the snippet editor won't support the angular components (PrimeNG) but you could probably paste it right into your project and it will work as expected.

Best of luck! :)

```css
.your-form label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.your-form input, .your-form textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/primeui/4.1.15/primeui-all.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/primeui/4.1.15/primeui-all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<section class="ui-g your-form">
  <div class="ui-g-12">
    <p>Please provide us with feedback with your experience ,your rate and/or leave comments this is to help us provide you with a better service.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-6 ui-sm-12">
    <label>First name *</label>
    <input type="text" pInputText name="firstName" maxlength="20" />
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-6 ui-sm-12">
    <label>Last name *</label>
    <input type="text" pInputText name="lastName" maxlength="20" />
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-6 ui-sm-12">
    <label>Middle name</label>
    <input type="text" pInputText name="middleName" maxlength="20" />
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-6 ui-sm-12">
    <!-- just a generic space in case you wanted to add an input next to middle name later -->
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-6 ui-sm-12">
    <label>UMN*</label>
    <input type="text" pInputText name="umn" maxlength="15" />
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-6 ui-sm-12">
    <label>Phone number *</label>
    <input type="text" pInputText name="phoneNumber" maxlength="10" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="ui-g">
    <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-12">
      <p-radioButton name="quickFeedBackGrade" value="1" label="Very poor"></p-radioButton>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-12">
      <p-radioButton name="quickFeedBackGrade" value="2" label="Poor"></p-radioButton>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-12">
      <p-radioButton name="quickFeedBackGrade" value="3" label="Good"></p-radioButton>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-12">
      <p-radioButton name="quickFeedBackGrade" value="4" label="Very good"></p-radioButton>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-12">
      <p-radioButton name="quickFeedBackGrade" value="5" label="Excellent"></p-radioButton>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-12">
      <!-- generic spacer for extra option -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-12">
    <label>Comments</label>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="60" pInputTextarea autoResize="autoResize" name="comments"></textarea>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you very much chris (still having some issues but hopefully will solve them )